# Equalize height on two floating divs when window size is greater than specified width, then return to original height when window width is below

Tags: jquery

I have the code right for equalizing the divs, but I'm at a loss for the "return to original height" part.

Here's the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/5fTXZ/1/

The jQuery:

```
// equalize height of columns
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
group.height(tallest);
}

// change to original height of columns
function originalHeight(group) {
    // not sure what to put here
}

// change height based on windows size
function checkWindowSize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        equalHeight($(".col"));
    } else {
        originalHeight($(".col"));
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
    checkWindowSize();
});
```

You can see if you change the window size of the output the divs will equalize in height when width is greater than 767px. If you change it back to below 767px in width it just calls the empty function that I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fTXZ/2/)**

Just remove `height` from elements:

```
function originalHeight(group) {
    group.css('height', '');
}
```